# Flask render template - does not return "failure.html"

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a function which looks like this

```
out = whitelist(params)

if out:
  return render_template("success.html")
else:
  return render_template("failure.html")
```

So the questions is failure.html is never rendered even though the output is empty. It always redirects to success ... I have printed output and it is indeed empty.

So more info:

whitelist is a function which does a bunch of things..

Comment: Sounds like `out` _isn't_ empty.  How are you printing it?  Have you tried printing its `repr`?  If it contains just spaces it could _look_ empty when it isn't.

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: What is whitelist? Also, try  `print out is None or out is ''` to actually check if `out` is empty. If it is a space it won't evaluate as `False`